# Own Shipping Module for Magento - Next step in onepage checkout does not work anymore

Tags: magento, module

Cheers,
I created my own shipping module for magento 1.4.1.1. , which so far does not work. After really getting frustrated with this, I exactly copied everything from http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/shipping/create-shipping-method-module .

As with my own module, it does not work. In the onepage checkout, I cannot go further when entering the shipping adress, and firebug indicates, that my shipping method does not appear in the list of available shipping options.

My model class indeed is loaded, I solved this problem earlier. But for some strange reason it will not appear in the frontend and again, I am currently using the exact files from the wiki.

Please, does anybody have any ideas what could be going wrong here?

Thanks in advance!

Edit: this is my config xml:

```
      <config>
    <modules>
  <!-- declare module's version information -->
      <YourCompany_NewModule>
  <!-- this version number will be used for database upgrades -->
        <version>0.1.0</version>
      </YourCompany_NewModule>
    </modules>
    <global>
  <!-- declare model group for new module -->
      <models>
  <!-- model group alias to be used in Mage::getModel() -->
        <newmodule>
  <!-- base class name for the model group -->
          <class>YourCompany_NewModule_Model</class>
        </newmodule>
      </models>
  <!-- declare resource setup for new module -->
      <resources>
  <!-- resource identifier -->
        <newmodule_setup>
  <!-- specify that this resource is a setup resource and used for upgrades -->
          <setup>
  <!-- which module to look for install/upgrade files in -->
            <module>YourCompany_NewModule</module>
          </setup>
  <!-- specify database connection for this resource -->
          <connection>
  <!-- do not create new connection, use predefined core setup connection -->
            <use>core_setup</use>
          </connection>
        </newmodule_setup>
      </resources>
    </global>
    <default>
            <carriers>
                <mage_newmodule>
                        <active>1</active>
                        <sallowspecific>0</sallowspecific>
    <model>newmodule/carrier_newmodule</model>
                        <name>New Module</name>
                        <title>New Module</title>
                        <specificerrmsg>
                            This shipping method is currently unavailable.
                            If you would like to ship using this shipping
                            method, please contact us.
                        </specificerrmsg>
                        <handling_type>F</handling_type>
                </mage_newmodule>
            </carriers>
    </default>
```

Comment: Can you post the XML configuration for your module? It's likely that Magento doesn't know about your shipping option at all.

Comment: Have you tried debugging this using xedbug and your IDE?  you can then find out why it's not displaying...

Comment: to be honest, I have no idea where to start... this error startet occuring just when specified the right model in my config. so i assume the error is there. what should I look for here? were else should I look or rather where are the sipping methods outputted?

Answer (score 0):

I could not get the wiki article to work.

Consequently I edited Flatrate.php and the config.xml for it so I coulds have more settings in the admin, e.g. London Congestion Charge.

This worked fine for me, but the someone had a benny because I hadn't bothered to do the over-ride in local.

It was a relative snip to get my customised Flatrate to my own model, I could then put the stock file back.

Hence I recommend the two-step approach. Over-ride the Flatrate by botching the core files, then when you have it working then put it out a separate module.

You are right that when it is messed up the checkout just does not work.